# Jenkins: is there a way to fail a build if it takes more than X time?

Tags: jenkins

I am looking for a way to fail a build if it will take more than X time (be it absolute (5 minutes -- example) or relative (10% more than the average of the last 5 builds -- example).

Is there any plugin to do that or should I build such functionality onto my running scripts?

I've been searching for plugins but couldn't find one that will mark a build as fail, only report build times.

Comment: Maybe https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [build timeout plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin):

> This plugin allows you to automatically abort a build if it's taking too long. Once the timeout is reached, Jenkins behaves as if an invisible hand has clicked the "abort build" button.

Comment: I have totally overlooked the fact that this plugin can actually mark the build as failed (the description and docs only talk about 'abort'). I'll try this one!

Answer (score 5):

A similar question was asked on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234204/timeout-on-a-build-step-of-jenkins).

You can use a [code timeout](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-timeout-code-enforce-time-limit) if your workflow steps are scripts. Otherwise, the [Build Timeout plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin) might do the trick.